# Select range in arrays, C

Tags: c, range

So i've got Array which i am supposed to calculate the average of index 1 to 5. index 0 and 6 are for another purpose. Can anyone help me out here?

Code:

```
int jumpnr = 0;
int jumpval[7];

for (jumpval=0; jumpval<7; jumpval++){
jumpnr = jumpnr++
printf("Enter the jumpdistance for the %d",jumpnr);
scanf(%d,&jumpval);
}

int average = jumpval[1] -> [5]; // <------- ? how 
printf("The average jumpdistance is: %d",average);
```

Comment: `for` from 1 to 5, `total += jumpval[i]`, then divide by 5. Also, use `&jumpval[jumpnr]` in your `scanf`.

Comment: hmm, i'm not quite sure how you mean. Would you please be so kind as to show me how you would do that?

Comment: Joel, I suggest you read a book. Your problem is really very simple and I feel you should do it yourself.

Comment: yeah i probably should... I know the math behind it but i'm unsure about the proper way to write it.

Comment: http://ideone.com/1P8fBm

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code it would be something like

```
initialize an int called 'sum' and set it to 0
for i from jumpval[1] to jumpval[5]
    sum+=jumpval[i]
```

Then divide sum by 5 would give you the average.

Comment: This is wrong... you probably mean `for i from 1 to 5`... who knows what is inside of `jumpval[1]` or `jumpval[5]`....... and even if you had `from 1 to 5`. dividing by 5 will not give you the average, but rather the floored average.... worse than not teaching a noobie is teaching him wrong stuff...